# Passing Email data to database using EWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, ssms, exchangewebservices

I'm currently working on a windows service that collects emails from a mailbox using the Exchange Web Service API, and passes the data from the emails to a stored procedure. The stored procedure then adds this data to a table in SSMS. I've tested the stored procedure manually and it functions fine. I've also got a method writing to a text file and all aspects of the emails (recipients, date, subject etc) are being collected.

My problem is that only the latest email in the mailbox is being passed to the database. Below is my code:

```
            int offset = 0;
            int pageSize = 50;
            bool moreEmails = true;
            ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);

            view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
            List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

            while (moreEmails)
            {
                foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    emails.Add((EmailMessage)item);
                }

                moreEmails = findResults.MoreAvailable;

                if (moreEmails)
                {
                    view.Offset += pageSize;
                }
            }

            PropertySet properties = (BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emails, properties);

            foreach (var EmailParam in emails)
            {
                FromEmail = EmailParam.From.ToString();
                EmailDate = EmailParam.DateTimeReceived.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                EmailSubject = EmailParam.Subject;
                EmailBody = EmailParam.Body;
                int SourceID = 1;

                foreach (var recipient in EmailParam.ToRecipients)
                {
                    ToEmail += recipient.Address.ToString();
                }

                foreach (var cc in EmailParam.CcRecipients)
                {
                    Emailcc += cc.Address.ToString();
                }

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("mtsp_CreateTicket", con);
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", EmailDate);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromEmail", FromEmail);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToEmail", ToEmail);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailSubject", EmailSubject);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailBody", EmailBody);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailcc", Emailcc);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceID", SourceID);
                    da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

It's my first time using a windows service and I'm sort of new to this so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If there are multiple entries in the emails collection, perhaps you are getting an exception and the code is aborting the loop?

Btw, you need to reset your ToEmail and Emailcc variables after closing the SqlConnection.

Comment: can you put more piece of code? i just see the part when you read the parameters of 1 email, where is the service? where is the for or while to read all emails?

Comment: @stevie_c There doesn't appear to be any exceptions being thrown. The text file I'm writing to shows all the data is being collected. This code is also in a try-catch and no exception there. Moreover, I assumed setting the ToEmail and Emailcc in the foreach loop would reset for every iteration?

Comment: @polzka90 I've added the code showing how I'm collecting the inbox emails.

Comment: do you try to put a log before this line PropertySet properties = (BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties); to see if the list is filled with all emails?

Comment: I would try a couple of things to debug this. Firstly I would run Sql Server Profiler to understand exactly what is being sent to the database. Secondly, I would remove the try/catch block just in case that's absorbing your exception.

Comment: Since you're using the += operator on ToEmail and Emailcc those variables will continue to grow on each iteration around the "emails" variable.

Comment: @stevie_c Replacing the "+=" operator with the "=" operator worked! Thanks!

Comment: Great. Just check that you're still storing all the email addresses for each email. As an improvement to your code you could separate the responsibilities of the method into separate classes and then you could use some unit tests to check that the behaviour is as you expect. Take a look at examples of SOLID principles and TDD online.